# Excel Not Finding Last Row Correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the last row in a sheet as part of my macro. One step before this one copies large amounts of data to Worksheet 4. When I get to this step, excel wrongly identifies the last row as some random row in my worksheet. I've tried `.Find` and countless other methods, and nothing seems to work.

```
Sub Step19MatchStrike()

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(4)

Dim LastRowColumnA As Long

LastRowColumnA = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("AA1").Value = "Strike Determination"
ws.Range("AA2").FormulaArray = "=IF((MATCH(E2,INDEX(Sheet3,(MATCH(A2,INDEX(Sheet3,,1),0)),5),0))>0,""To Keep"",""To Delete"")"
ws.Range("AA2").Copy ws.Range("AA3:AA" & LastRowColumnA)
ws.Columns(27).Value = ws.Columns(27).Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198338/discussion-on-question-by-gitty-excel-not-finding-last-row-correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want

```
Sub Step19MatchStrike()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim lRow As Long

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("AA1").Value = "Strike Determination"

        '~~> Fill the formula in one go
        .Range("AA2:AA" & lRow).FormulaArray = YOURFORMULA
        .Columns(27).Value = .Columns(27).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I am just curious about `Sheet3` in your formula. That doesn't look right

`"=IF((MATCH(E2,INDEX(Sheet3,(MATCH(A2,INDEX(Sheet3,,1),0)),5),0))>0,""To Keep"",""To Delete"")"`

**Edit**

Using Autofill

```
Sub Step19MatchStrike()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim lRow As Long

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("AA1").Value = "Strike Determination"
        .Range("AA2").FormulaArray = "=IF((MATCH(E2,INDEX(Sheet3,(MATCH(A2,INDEX(Sheet3,,1),0)),5),0))>0,""To Keep"",""To Delete"")"
        .Range("AA2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AA2:AA" & lRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, formula arrays cannot be filled down that way. I've tried it multiple times and done a lot of research- the formulas become absolute for some reason...

Comment: Can you share the exact formula?

Comment: Sheet3 is a range that basically refers to Worksheets(3)

Comment: `.Range("AA2").FormulaArray = YOURFORMULA`, then `.Range("AA2").AutoFill Destination:= .Range("AA2:AA" & lRow)` perhaps, if I got my syntax right.

Comment: The formula is the one I posted above. When I copy it down the range, E2 becomes E3 and so on. When I fill down the formula, E2 remains absolute and doesn't change accordingly.

Comment: @Gitty can you try with `AutoFill` as noted above?

Comment: @Gitty: You can enter a formula array in one go. See [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray) but if you want it to change then use Autofill. One moment. updating the post

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid the usage of worksheet index.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Refer to the worksheet using CodeName (the name appears in the VBA editor)
        Set ws = ws1
        'Refer to the worksheet using Name (the name appears in the Excel sheet)
        Set ws = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End With

    'Create as With Statement to avoid sheet repetition
    With ws
        'Find the last row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen the answer only show how to avoid the usage of worksheet index. if there is an issue should i delete the answer?

Comment: i have edit the answer to show how to calculated last row.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i prefer it too. to avoid errors if the user accidentally change the sheet name in the workbook